# [quanteda]: remove text between two characters

Tags: quanteda

I am hoping for advice on removing text from a corpus of 833 text files. I want to remove any text contained within # characters. For example:

#Monday, 17 November 2027#

It is necessary to repeat some of the rhetoric contained in the government's national forest policy statement and compare it with reality. It states:

#the governments must establish clear and consistent policies for resource development, providing secure access to resources and consistent environmental guidelines.
. . . . . . . . .
A range of sustainable forest based industries, founded on excellence and innovation, will be expanding to contribute further to regional and national economic and employment growth.
. . . . . . . . .
. . .. governments acknowledge their role in seeking to minimise any adverse social and economic effects of the structural adjustment process, particularly where alternative employment is not always available.#

Extensive areas of productive forest, which have sustained rural economies and jobs throughout NSW for decades, have quickly been declared national park and wilderness. This action has occurred before Regional Forest Agreements have been completed.

I want only the following text:

It is necessary to repeat some of the rhetoric contained in the government's national forest policy statement and compare it with reality. It states:

Extensive areas of productive forest, which have sustained rural economies and jobs throughout NSW for decades, have quickly been declared national park and wilderness. This action has occurred before Regional Forest Agreements have been completed.

The file structure follows:

txtdata = readtext("E:/H/Data/*")
readtext object consisting of 833 documents and 0 docvars.

## Description: df [833 × 2]

doc_id          text
           
1 #10_3-7-98.txt  ""#Date Frid"..."
2 #11_2-7-98.txt  ""#Date Thur"..."
3 #12_30-6-98.txt ""#Date Tues"..."
4 #13_29-6-98.txt ""#Date Mond"..."
5 #14_29-6-98.txt ""#Date Mond"..."
6 #15_29-6-98.txt ""# Date Mon"..."

## … with 827 more rows

Comment: Per your comment, this appears to have solved your problem: [\[readtext\]: download files from the Internet to remove text via stringi and read the file into Quanteda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770022/readtext-download-files-from-the-internet-to-remove-text-via-stringi-and-read)

Answer (score 0):

No real need for **quanteda** here, you can remove the spans between `#` characters using regular expression replacement. I prefer the excellent **stringi** package for this.

The regular expression removes all characters (`.*`) between spans and the `\n{2}` cleans things up a bit by also removing the two newline characters present after the removed span.

```r
txt <- "#Monday, 17 November 2027#

It is necessary to repeat some of the rhetoric contained in the government's national forest policy statement and compare it with reality. It states:

#the governments must establish clear and consistent policies for resource development, providing secure access to resources and consistent environmental guidelines. . . . . . . . . . A range of sustainable forest based industries, founded on excellence and innovation, will be expanding to contribute further to regional and national economic and employment growth. . . . . . . . . . . . .. governments acknowledge their role in seeking to minimise any adverse social and economic effects of the structural adjustment process, particularly where alternative employment is not always available.#

Extensive areas of productive forest, which have sustained rural economies and jobs throughout NSW for decades, have quickly been declared national park and wilderness. This action has occurred before Regional Forest Agreements have been completed."

library("stringi")
stri_replace_all_regex(txt, "#.*#\n{2}", "") |>
    cat()
#> It is necessary to repeat some of the rhetoric contained in the
#> government's national forest policy statement and compare it with 
#> reality.  It states:
#> 
#> Extensive areas of productive forest, which have sustained rural
#> economies and jobs throughout NSW for decades, have quickly been 
#> declared national park and wilderness. This action has occurred before
#> Regional Forest Agreements have been completed.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. How do I apply this code to all 833 files, so I can read the directory in Quanteda ? I looked at the manual but it also used a single  file example. I tried substituting the directory path for 'txt' but this could not be read back into Quanteda via readtext. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a problem or question about **readtext** you would need to file an issue or a SO question that is reproducible. But once you’ve read the files into a character vector (or corpus) then the same `stri_replace_all_regex()` will work on the vector.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the job:

> Blockquote

```
x - list.files("C:/Data/files/*", recursive = TRUE) 
library("stringi")
stri_replace_all_regex(x, "#.*#\n{2}", "") |>
 cat()
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: See this thread - this approach solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770022/readtext-download-files-from-the-internet-to-remove-text-via-stringi-and-read/76771242#76771242